# cansend command doesn't send a frame from can0 to can1

Tags: can-bus, canutils

I need to send a frame from can0 to can1 and vice versa. 
So, first I log candump output to a file like this: `candump can1 -n 1 > /tmp/CANDUMP &`
Then I send the frame: `cansend can0 128#00FF00FF00FF00FF`

It only works if I send a frame from can1 to can1 or can0 to can0... Wonder why?

Answer (score 1):

> It only works if I send a frame from can1 to can1 or can0 to can0... Wonder why?

cansend command takes 2 arguments. The first one is can-device ID, here the device is **on which you want to send the data** which means *cansend can0* will publish the data on the canbus 0 on your system.

If you want to send data from can0 to can1 you can physically connect them to the same bus.